# Twilio resource binding returns "The requested resource /Services//Bindings was not found"

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When I try to do binding, I always get the error 20404:

> {"error":{"status":404,"message":"The requested resource 
>   /Services//Bindings was not
>   found","code":20404,"moreInfo":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404"},"message":"Failed
>   to create binding: Error: The requested resource /Services//Bindings
>   was not found"}'

Here is the code which does the binding

```
service.bindings.create(binding).then((binding) => {
    console.log(binding);
    // Send a JSON response indicating success
    return {
      status: 200,
      data: {message: 'Binding created!'},
};
```

Comment: You're trying to bind something that isn't there. Have you followed the link in the moreInfo attribute?

Comment: I figured it out, the service sid was not correct